# Use "*" as argument of function main()

Tags: c, shell, arguments, program-entry-point

When I want to use `*` as an argument of function `main()`, the shell will expand it to the all files in the current directory. How to avoid this?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    for(int i=0; i<argc-1; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

On the command line, it will output:

```
atlas@localhost ~/D/P/C> ./expr 2 3 4 + *
13
./expr 
2 
3 
4 
+ 
Command.c 
Readlines.c 
catlas.h 
expr 
expr.c 
find 
find.c
```

Comment: Did you tried to escape it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` is a special *wildcard* used in shell context. The shell will always expand the `*` before it is *actually* passed to your program. To take the input of `*` as a command line argument character, you can enclose the `*` in quotes, like `"*"`or use an escape character `\*`, as suggested in other answers, to stop the expansion.

Otherwise, The expansion of `*` is being performed by the shell before it is *passed* to your program.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `*` while giving the input. `\*`. So we have to mention to shell that is not a wild card. It is character.